# accessing variables within function

Tags: php, oop

just trying to understand this code.

```
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$query = $db->query(...);

foreach ($query->rows as $setting) {
...
}
```

I haven't seen this before: `$query->rows`
Does this mean that the `for-each loop` in accessing the variable `rows` within the function `query`?

Comment: Query is not a function , you are accesing rows from the object query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means `$query` is an Object, not a function. `rows` is a property of that object. A dumbed down `query` class could look like:

```
class Classname {
    public $rows;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rows = 0;
    }
}
```

Where `$db->query(...);` returns an object of type `Classname`. Probably the real name is something like `Query`. Of course the class for your actual object is much more complex and `rows` is an array.

Comment: ye lol (brain freeze), as soon as i posted this question it clicked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$query` returns an array of data from the database by the given `...` query.